# How to read a message using TKInterface?

Tags: python, python-2.7, button, text, tkinter

This is the "click me" function which runs when the button on the interface is clicked.

```
def click_me():
    file_name = file_name_entry.get()
    the_file_name = str(file_name)
    open(the_file_name, "r")
    imp_message = file.read(the_file_name)
```

There is a grey line beneath `the_file_name` in brackets and when hovered over says: passing str instead of file - is this intentional?

```
    password_output.delete(0.0, END)
    password_output.insert(END, imp_message)
```

The relevant TKInter code is as follows...

```
file_name_entry = Entry(encrypt_frame, width=20)
file_name_entry.grid(column = 1, row = 1, sticky = W)
Button(encrypt_frame, text= "Submit", command = click_me).grid(column = 2, row = 1)
```

The error output is:
`IOError: Errno22 invalid mode ('r/) or filename ""`

Comment: The first error sounds like something that your editor is suggesting.  Second, you are never assigning the open file to anything, so `file.read(...)` is not going to work since `file` (as far as we can see) has not been assigned.  Also, using `file` as a variable name is not a good idea.

Comment: why is "file." even necessary? the filename is already assigned by the_file_name so it is useful?

Comment: [Reading and writing files](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is close, but you're trying to read from the file name rather than the opened file object. Change your code to this:

```
file=open(the_file_name, "r")
imp_message = file.read()
```

Better yet, use a context manager which will automatically close the file when you're done:

```
with open(the_file_name, "r") as f:
    imp_message = f.read()
```

The python documentation has a nice tutorial on reading and writing files:

- Python 2 - [Reading and writing files](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)
- Python 3 - [Reading and writing files](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)

Unrelated to the actual question, there are a couple problems with your code.

First, there's no need for this statement:

```
the_file_name = str(file_name)
```

In this case, `file_name` is already a string since it is coming from an `Entry` widget.

Second, the index `0.0` in the statement `password_output.delete(0.0, END)` is incorrect. Text widget indexes must be strings in the form of *<line>*.*<column>*, and lines start at 1 (one). The proper index for the first character is the string `"1.0"`.